# XMPP server won't authenticate users

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire

Using JS and Strophe to create a messaging application. Using Strophe to handle the connection and I can't seem to log in using credentials that aren't admin. I'm trying to dynamically pull them from the login form, which is working as far as I can tell. The user is successfully logged into the api, but not the XMPP server (hosted on OpenFire).

Tried using Pidgin as a proxy to test the credentials. Admin account logs in, but all others disconnect immediately on port 7070, and fail to authenticate in port 5222. As far as I can tell, the authentication credentials are correct. I even created a couple on the fly and tested those to no avail even though they show up in OpenFire and log in through the ajax call to the api.

Strophe log

```
Strophe is connecting.
xmpp.js:6 0 : _throttledRequestHandler called with 1 requests
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 1.0 posting
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 1.0 state changed to 1
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 1.1 state changed to 2
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 1.1 state changed to 3

xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 1.1 state changed to 4
xmpp.js:6 0 : removing request
xmpp.js:6 0 : _throttledRequestHandler called with 0 requests
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 1 should now be removed
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 1.1 got 200
xmpp.js:6 1 : _connect_cb was called
xmpp.js:6 0 : _throttledRequestHandler called with 0 requests
xmpp.js:6 0 : _throttledRequestHandler called with 1 requests
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 2.0 posting
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 2.0 state changed to 1
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 2.1 state changed to 2
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 2.1 state changed to 3
strophe.js:4839 XHR finished loading: POST 

xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 2.1 state changed to 4
xmpp.js:6 0 : removing request
xmpp.js:6 0 : _throttledRequestHandler called with 0 requests
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 2 should now be removed
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 2.1 got 200
xmpp.js:6 1 : _dataRecv called
xmpp.js:6 0 : _throttledRequestHandler called with 0 requests
xmpp.js:6 0 : _throttledRequestHandler called with 1 requests
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 3.0 posting
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 3.0 state changed to 1
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 3.1 state changed to 2
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 3.1 state changed to 3
strophe.js:4839 XHR finished loading: POST 

xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 3.1 state changed to 4
xmpp.js:6 0 : removing request
xmpp.js:6 0 : _throttledRequestHandler called with 0 requests
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 3 should now be removed
xmpp.js:6 0 : request id 3.1 got 200
xmpp.js:6 1 : _dataRecv called
xmpp.js:21 4
xmpp.js:35 Strophe failed to authenticate.
```

Username: s

Password: s

email: s

```
const BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://xmpp.sitr.com:7070/http-bind/';
var connection = null;

    Strophe.log = function(level, msg) {
        console.log(level + ' : ' + msg);
    };


function onConnect(status){

    console.log(status);

    if(status==Strophe.Status.CONNECTING){
        console.log('Strophe is connecting.');
        //Strophe.log;
    }else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL){
        console.log('Strophe failed to connect.');

    }else if (status== Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING){
        console.log('Strophe is disconnecting.');

    }else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED){
        console.log('Strophe is disconnected.');
    }else if (status == Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL){
        console.log('Strophe failed to authenticate.');
    }else if(status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED){
        console.log('Strophe is connected.');
         $('#notifications').html('<p class="welcome">Hello! Any new posts will appear below.</p>');
        connection.addHandler(notifyUser, null, 'message', null, null,  null);
        connection.send($pres().tree());
    }

}

function XMPP(xmppUser, password, email) {
    //console.log(xmppUser, password, email);

//XMPP is called in global.js in login function. Passes arguments.
    var connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE).connect(
                            xmppUser + '@xmpp.site.com',
                            password, 
                            onConnect);

    };
```

Comment: I can't seem to see code that even attempts to log in using any credentials at all

Comment: Scuse me, fogot to add in the second paragraph.

Comment: Have you simply tried to login the user from Pidgin? What was the outcome of login in Pidgin?

Comment: This problem has evolved a bit. First of all, the issue at the time of writing this was that the API was passing on encrypted passwords to the XMPP server causing the Auth issue. That's been fixed.

Now, when I try to send and reccieve messages(the .addHandler broke first) I get an error suggesting the var connection is null. 

As far as I can tell, it's not or else it wouldn't be able to connect w/ the XMPP server.